# Round Function in Snowflake giving error" expected 2, got 3"

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am getting error for round function in snowflake.
Below is the error

> too many arguments for function CAST(ROUND(CAST(ColumnName AS FLOAT), 0, 1)) expected 2, got 3

Below is the function converted from SQL Query to Snowflake Query

```
CAST(ROUND(CAST(ColumnName AS FLOAT),0,1) AS INT)
```

This is working fine in SQL.
Below is the SQL Query:

```
CAST(ROUND(CONVERT(FLOAT,ColumnName),0,1) AS INT) AS 'Column_Name'
```

Answer (score 0):

The [ROUND()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/round.html) function takes just 2 not 3.

ROUND( <input_expr> [, <scale_expr> ] )

Your sql has 3 :

```
ROUND(    col    ,0,1)
```

Just choose whether you want 0 or 1 decimals and drop either the 0 or 1

[image]

As you're casting back to an INT you'd probably just want 0 decimals.

You may be better off just casting straight to an INT - but without other context | sample data this is just a guess.

[image]